# javascript object contents assign by reference, is that possible?

Tags: javascript, object

i want to store data in two different structured objects eg.:

```
MS = {              
    waypoints:
        { 'wpg0' : 'content',
          'id' : 'uuid1'
                    }
};

InvertedMS = {
    'uuid1': { 'wpg0' : 'content'
             }
};
```

Is it (and how) possible to set 'content' in a way to be updated in both objects as it gets updated in one of the two?

[here my experimental jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69KCr/)

Comment: thanks to jAndy's answer I created this jsfiddle, which demonstrates the pass-by-reference in javascript (within objects) http://jsfiddle.net/efrZH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is very possible. But you would need a pure *Object reference* and not a *primitive value*. Since ECMAscript effectively only passes *referecens* around, this pretty much implies what you want. For instance

```
var sharedData = { };

waypoint = {
    wpg0: sharedData
};

InvertedMS = {
    uuid1: { 
        wpg0: sharedData
    }
};
```

Now, later if you change anything in `sharedData`, all references to it will reflect those changes.

```
sharedData.update = 42;

console.log( InvertedMS.uuid1.wpg0.update ); // 42

waypoint.wpg0.update = 82;

console.log( InvertedMS.uuid1.wpg0.update ); // 82
```