# issue with the reference function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
//bob first initialization
var bob = function()
{
    console.log('bob');
};

//set jan to bob via reference
var jan = bob;

//set bob to another function
bob = function()
{
    console.log('newbob');
};

jan(); //console.logs 'bob'
bob(); //console.logs 'newbob'


</script>
```

Question:

why `jan()`; outputs `bob`, not `newbob`? since `jan()` is the reference of `bob()`

Comment: Check this out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316954/javascript-object-contents-assign-by-reference-is-that-possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `var jan = bob;`, both `jan` and `bob` are references to the same function.

`bob = function() {}` assigns a reference to a new function to `bob`

`jan` still contains a reference to the original function.

i.e. You are changing the value of the variable, you aren't changing the function that the variable referred to.

---

To compare:

```
var a = { f: function () { console.log(1); } };
var b = a;
a.f = function () { console.log(2); };
```

Now `a` and `b` contain references to the same object. The object contains a reference to a function. When you assign a new function to that object property the `a.f` and `b.f` both change because `a` and `b` are still both references to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

jan and bob are just two variables that happened to point to the same function at one point in time, but the assignment of a new value to one of them doesn't have any effect on the value assigned to the other. It's like:

```
var a = 1;
var b = a; // a and b evaluate to 1
var a = 2; // a evaluates to 2, b evaluates to 1 (a's
           // assignment has no effect on b)
```